# Programmatically access output of azure pipeline runs?

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

Is there an SDK or cli tooling to retrieve the logging output of steps from azure pipeline runs ?

I'd really like to be able to grep into the output of a given template I am changing for prior runs

**update** ...
this looks hopeful  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/logs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Hi Scott; the azure devops rest api is exactly the tool you want, as you discovered. If you would like to post that as an answer, that'd be great.